# Android getInboxIntent empty

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to develop a turn based game but I have a problem. 
When I use

```
Intent intent = Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getInboxIntent(getApiClient());
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES);
```

the inbox is always empty whereas if I check from google app I see current games and invitations.

I get this message in error logs:

> Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

Any ideas of the problem?